# Regarding BigBlueButton implementation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, bigbluebutton

I am trying to integrate bigbluebutton into Codeigniter and after complete set i am not able to create meeting and other things.. below is the code

```
<?php


// Require the bbb-api file:
require_once('../includes/bbb-api.php');


// Instatiate the BBB class:
$bbb = new BigBlueButton();

/* ___________ CREATE MEETING w/ OPTIONS ______ */
/* 
*/
$creationParams = array(
    'meetingId' => '1234',                  // REQUIRED
    'meetingName' => 'Test Meeting Name',   // REQUIRED
    'attendeePw' => 'ap',                   // Match this value in getJoinMeetingURL() to join as attendee.
    'moderatorPw' => 'mp',                  // Match this value in getJoinMeetingURL() to join as moderator.
    'welcomeMsg' => '',                     // ''= use default. Change to customize.
    'dialNumber' => '',                     // The main number to call into. Optional.
    'voiceBridge' => '',                    // PIN to join voice. Optional.
    'webVoice' => '',                       // Alphanumeric to join voice. Optional.
    'logoutUrl' => '',                      // Default in bigbluebutton.properties. Optional.
    'maxParticipants' => '-1',              // Optional. -1 = unlimitted. Not supported in BBB. [number]
    'record' => 'false',                    // New. 'true' will tell BBB to record the meeting.
    'duration' => '0',                      // Default = 0 which means no set duration in minutes. [number]
    //'meta_category' => '',                // Use to pass additional info to BBB server. See API docs.
);

// Create the meeting and get back a response:
$itsAllGood = true;
try {$result = $bbb->createMeetingWithXmlResponseArray($creationParams);}
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        $itsAllGood = false;
    }

if ($itsAllGood == true) {
    // If it's all good, then we've interfaced with our BBB php api OK:
    if ($result == null) {
        // If we get a null response, then we're not getting any XML back from BBB.
        echo "Failed to get any response. Maybe we can't contact the BBB server.";
    }   
    else { 
    // We got an XML response, so let's see what it says:
    print_r($result);
        if ($result['returncode'] == 'SUCCESS') {
            // Then do stuff ...
            echo "<p>Meeting succesfullly created.</p>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Meeting creation failed.</p>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And what parameters have to pass to create meeting in url